# Update label Per Web browser Refresh at a specific time using c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Actually am a beginner in c#..And my question is how can i update label per web browser refresh at a specific time using c#, assuming i set my timer to 30 sec using the textbox so i want my web to refresh at the exact time and add the hit to a label, i mean the number of time it has refresh to the label.....In vb.net the syntax is as the code below

```
Dim x as integer

    x = x + 1         
If x = TextBox.Text Then
             WebBrowser1.Refresh()
             x = 0             
Label.Text = Val(Label.Text) + 1         
End If
```

So how can i achieve something like these in c#

Comment: How hard did you try? Maybe you should pick up a book at your local library called C# for Dummies. >That would be a great start for you. Every is written in a simple way and they start from the beginning since they are for beginners.

Comment: @Chillzy Thanks, i will do that....

Comment: at the very least go to google and type vb.net to c# converter.

Comment: i have already done that but after i convert the code to c#...it's still not working

Comment: `how can a perform a web browser refresh at a specific time using c#` I am confused since that is clearly not what your VB code is doing. Do you want refresh at a specific time? Or do you want to convert the VB code?

Comment: @mjwills i want to refresh at a specific time

Answer (score 0):

```
private void page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = (30 * 1000); // 30 secs
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_event);
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //refresh here...
}
```

Also you can reload using onload in  HTML as:

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout('window.location.reload()',1000);">
```

Comment: @srinivas...How do i add update my form with the latest data through the label

Comment: And is there a way i can change the timer interval through the textbox....

Comment: i tried something these "timer.Interval = textbox.text; but it's giving error 'cannot implicitly convert type string to int'

Comment: Try this code   timer.Interval = convert.toInt32( textbox.text);       Also Make sure you have integer in the textbox val

Comment: There are at least 3 typos in your latest comment @SrinivasGV.

Comment: @srinvas how do i update my form with latest Data when the timer start...i mean when a given time is exhausted..i want to be able to add the work done to a label....i set my label to '0' when one is done the label should turn one...when two refresh is done , it should turn to turn etc

Comment: @mjwills can you guide me through these